# Have not had success chaining these two ffmpeg commands

Tags: java, filter, ffmpeg, chaining

Both commands work well, but I need to chain them, need help

```
ffcommand1 = new String[]{"-ss", "00:00:00", "-t", sduration, "-y", "-i", pathDir + fname, "-vf", "scale=640:480", "-s", "640x480", "-r", "15", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "2097152", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-vf", "scale=640:480,drawtext=fontfile=" + homeDir + "opensansregular.ttf:fontsize=" + fontsize + ":fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:text='" + subtitle + "':x=100:y=350", "-c:a", "copy", "-an", pathDir + fname1};


ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f lavfi -i "color=0x1f477000:s=640x480" -filter_complex "blend=shortest=1:all_mode=overlay:all_opacity=0.7" output.mp4
```

Comment: Does `input.mp4` in command #2 = `fname1` from command #1?

Comment: No. I have used them in two different functions. the variables are not the same. I'd like to make them the same, if I get a combined command, I will use "fname" as source file, and fname1 as destination file.

Answer (score 0):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -y -t 30 -i input.mp4 -f lavfi -i "color=0x1f477000:s=640x480:r=15" -filter_complex "[0]fps=15,scale=640:480[main];[main][1]blend=shortest=1:all_mode=overlay:all_opacity=0.7,drawtext=fontfile=opensansregular.ttf:fontsize=22:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:text='your text':x=100:y=350" -vcodec mpeg4 -b:v 2097152 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

- `-ss 00:00:00` does nothing so this has been removed from the combined command.
- You are using both `-c:a copy` ([stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) audio) and `-an` (no audio). I assumed you want to keep the audio, so `-an` has been omitted.
- `-b:a`, `-ac`, and `-ar` are ignored with `-c:a copy` so these options have been omitted.
- You are using scale 3 times (two scale filters and `-s` option). I reduced it to one scale instance.
- Do you really want to use `-c:v mpeg4`? That outputs MPEG-4 Part 2 video which is an old, legacy format. If you remove `-c:v mpeg4` it will output H.264 instead for MP4.

Comment: WOW it worked great. on windows, no changes had to be made.  thank you thank you.

on Android I had to add setdar=4/3

When I removed -c:v mpeg4  the command broke, so not sure how to do this one, can you elaborate on this?

another discovery was that the color value from android doesn't translate to ffmpeg, I put a reddish color, ffmpeg shows a greenish color. is there an option on ffmpeg that I missed?

Comment: I experimented a bit more, I was passing ARGB instead of RGBA. After I corrected it, I saw the colors between android setcolorfilter() and ffmpeg. the only difference now I see more  transparency on ffmpeg output than android. on Android the red filter doesn't allow you to see the picture, ffmpeg output does. My assumption was that AA will have set the transparency. the command used is n the next comment

Comment: ffmpeg  -y -t 00:00:03 -i /data/user/0/com.example.ufco/files/MYrender/CFtmp.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=0xFF092EED:s=640x480:r=15 -filter_complex [0]fps=15,setdar=4/3,scale=640:480[main];[main][1]blend=shortest=1:all_mode=overlay -vcodec mpeg4 -b:v 2097152 -c:a copy /data/user/0/com.example.ufco/files/MYrender/CF1-615366424.mp4

Comment: Question: given that I'm passing the alpha in RRGGBBAA, ffmpeg is applying opacity of the alpha value, then why should I confuse things with all_opacity=0.xx. Or does all_opacity has a different definition? Should I also set the all_opacity value in the ffmpeg command?

Comment: @Plazar99 Forgot to mention that color filter is yuv420p, so has no alpha capabilities. So if you want alpha with color filter you need to use format filter to change to a pixel format with alpha (such as yuva420p) and then a filter such as colorchannelmixer to change alpha level. But all of this is straying from the original question which I already answered. You should ask 1 question per post instead of asking multiple follow-up questions. If you need more help regarding this color/transparency stuff ask a new question.

Comment: ok, one question: does all_opacity percentage work as alpha setting in yuv420p format?

Comment: @Plazar99 Yes, you can use `all_opacity` to change opacity of blend even with non-alpha inputs.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, this is the command that I landed on. I still see some colors mismatches between ffmpeg and android shades of colors. since I'm working on a proof of concept project, it will have to do. but thank you so much for all of your help. I'm still a bit curious about removing -vcodec mpeg4, and how it will impact the outcome, but I think I should not prolong this case. it is solved. thank you all.

Comment: ffmpeg  -y -t 00:00:05 -i /data/user/0/com.example.ufco/files/MYrender/CFtmp1.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=0xD50019:s=640x480:r=15 -filter_complex [0]fps=15,setdar=4/3,scale=640:480[main];[main][1]blend=shortest=1:all_mode=overlay:all_opacity=0.66 -vcodec mpeg4 -b:v 2097152 -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuva420p /data/user/0/com.example.ufco/files/MYrender/CF1-12-462557994.mp4